# Using Bundler with Git, is https:// or git:// better?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github, bundler

Using bundler to install a gem from github, there are two obvious choices; `https://` or `git://`.

From the default rails template;

```
gem "rails", :git => "git://github.com/rails/rails"
```

But, when viewing the [rails repo on github](https://github.com/rails/rails), the default clone url is the `https://` url.

Copying and pasting straight from github, I'd end up with;

```
gem "rails", :git => "https://github.com/rails/rails.git"
```

These two lines are almost the same, but not quite.

Is there any benefit to `git://` over `https://`?

Is one of them faster to do a `bundle install`?

Is doing an `https://` checkout easier to cache from githubs perspective?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They will be pretty much the same. If you are behind a firewall etc. you might consider the `https` one. `git` protocol might be slightly faster ( and is read-only), but it is negligible.

If you don't care about firewall, use git protocol for bundler purposes as it is the right intent - read only clone of a repo.

Comment: Sounds like a definitive answer. I'll default to `:git => "git://...`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The git protocol gives better performance and reliability, but on a host with a web server set up, http exports may be simpler to set up.

follow git user manual.
http://schacon.github.com/git/user-manual.html#exporting-via-http